# using $q in multiple Angular factories with UI state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular-ui-states and before hiting the template, I have to resolve a few HTTP requests. My current problem is where exactly to make ise of promises.

example of state reolve:

```
resolve: {
  prepareData: function($q, setupService, $stateParams) {
      console.log('resolving');
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      setupService.fetchData($stateParams).then(function(response) {
          console.log('back, ', response);
          deferred.resolve();
          return deferred.promise;
      });
  }
}
```

in my factory:

```
services.factory('setupService', [ '...', '$q', function(..., $q) {
    return {
        fetchData: function(urlParams) {
            console.log('starting to validade');
            oneService.httpfunction().then(function (response) {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    // do some non http stuff
                    // call another factory which makes a http request
                    anotherservice.anotherfunction().then(function (data) {
                        if (etc) {
                            return data;
                        } else if(etc) {
                            return data;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

My state waits correctly for the services to finish, but in the end I'm not going back to the state resolve (I am never printing ('back', response)), basically setupService.fetchData() is not getting a value back. Am I missing $q also in the factories? Sorry my knowledge on the $q is not big. Thanks for support

**UPDATE**

Figure out what was wrong. By adding $q.defer(); on my fetchData service, everything works fine. So instead of `return data`, `deferred.resolve(data)` and then return the promise. Thanks for support

Comment: You can not return data from another service inside the service, since the scope of variable is limited to that function? Try collecting date in rootscope and then return it at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out what was wrong. By adding $q.defer(); on my fetchData service, everything works fine. So instead of return data, deferred.resolve(data) and then return the promise. Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `deferred.promise;` after `setupService.fetchData()` function.

**your resolve is empty pass response as parameter to resolve that**

```
deferred.resolve(response); //resolve response
```

**state resolve**

```
resolve: {
    prepareData: function($q, setupService, $stateParams) {
        console.log('resolving');
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        setupService.fetchData($stateParams).then(function(response) {
            console.log('back, ', response);
            deferred.resolve(response); // resolve response.
        });
    return deferred.promise; // return resolved promise...
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo. My return deferred.promise is in this line actually. I am never printing ('back', response) so im not getting back at that moment already.

Comment: your resolve is empty, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the sollution. I found out the problem, see my question update.